# The results for username and password return false when they are true

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I enter the username and password on the form it says wrong username and password even though that is the username and password in the data base, I'm not sure why it is skipping over the if statement and going to else.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="id297187_jk05454"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="id297187_members"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 


$sql="SELECT userid FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and  password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=$result['num_rows'];

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count>0){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file     "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header('Location:login_success.php');
exit;
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: First of all, try to display the query generated (`echo $sql;`) and analyze the result. If you execute the exact same request on phpmyadmin, do you have a result ? Maybe there is a type error :)

Comment: give us the var_dump($_POST)

Comment: this is what i get when i display the query: SELECT userid FROM members WHERE username='john' and password='(password)'

Comment: And the password in your database is `(password)`?

Comment: the password is not to get into the database, it's for the website, the password is stored in the database, and that is 1234

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined

```
session_start();
```

also session_register is depreciated and removed from php5.4, use the global var

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
```

also check your password input has the name of

```
name="mypassword"
```

you may want to sanitize your $_POST vars as they are vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Ok, so i am a bit new to sql, should i put     session_start();  above the $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;   group

Comment: from the query you have echo'd out, it looks like there is a issue with your form it's self, as it's submitting the password (password) which should be 1234. Check your form name attribute on the password field. session_start() should be at the top of your script, and every script you will be using the session on. You can write to the session using $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; after the session_start() is defined.

Comment: ok so it looke like whenever i put the password in wrong, it get taken to the success page but when the password is correct i am told it is wrong